# Project Euler 37

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to solve Project Euler's problem number 37. Here's the link of the problem statement:

http://projecteuler.net/problem=37

Here's my code for the same:

```
def is_prime(n):
    i = 2
    while i<n:
        if(n%i == 0):
            return False
        i+=1
    return True

def left_truncable(num):
    li = []
    x = str(num)
    if(is_prime(num)):
        n = len(x)
        check = ""
        i = 1
        while(i<n):
            if(is_prime(int(x[i:]))):
                check = "True"
                i+=1
            else:
                check = "False"
                break
        if(check == "True"):
            li.append(num)
    return li

def right_truncable(num1):
    ri = []
    x1 = str(num1)
    if(is_prime(num1)):
        n = len(x1)
        check = ""
        j = 1
        while(j<n):
            if(is_prime(int(x1[:j]))):
                check = "True"
                j+=1
            else:
                check = "False"
                break
        if(check == "True"):
            ri.append(num1)
    return ri

def common_elements(list1, list2):
    return [element for element in list1 if element in list2]

right = []
for e in range(1, 1000):
    r = right_truncable(e)
    if(r != []):
        right.append(r)


left = []
for f in range(1, 1000):
    l = left_truncable(f)
    if(l != []):
        left.append(l)        

print common_elements(right, left)
```

Basically, I have created a function to find all the right truncable primes and left truncable primes. Then made separate lists for both type of prime numbers and then found out the common elements from both the lists. However, I get more than 11 truncable prime numbers in the first 1000 digits itself. Here's what my output for the above code looks like:

```
[[11], [13], [17], [23], [31], [37], [53], [71], [73], [113], [131], [137], [173], [197], [311], [313], [317], [373], [797]]
```

What seems to be the problem with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 isn't a prime number, so numbers like 11, 31, 71, 131 aren't truncatable from left to right.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that in my 'is_prime' function ! Thanks.